# Create with arguments [Laravel 5.2]

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I want to use a argument in a create action, but when I try to access the action:

> Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\AdsDiagController::create()

Here is the create action:

```
public function create($id){
    $record = TestRecord::findOrFail($id);
    return view("adsdiag.create", ["record" => $record]);
}
```

Here is the link to the action:

`<a href="{!! action('AdsDiagController@create', $record->id ) !!}">Create</a>`

And the route:

```
Route::resource('adsdiag', 'AdsDiagController');
```

I'm newbie in laravel, and I'm really confused with routes.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem you should use in your `route.php`

```
Route::get('adsdiag/{id}/',AdsDiagController@create);
```

**Reason**

When you call `Route::resource('adsdiag', 'AdsDiagController')` it generates these routes

```
Route::get('adsdiag','AdsDiagController@index');
Route::post('adsdiag','AdsDiagController@store');
Route::get('adsdiag/create','AdsDiagController@create'); // you can see that create method doesn't have any arguments here.
Route::get('adsdiag/show/{id}','AdsDiagController@show');
Route::post('adsdiag/update','AdsDiagController@update');
Route::get('adsdiag/edit/{id}','AdsDiagController@edit');
Route::delete('adsdiag/destroy/{id}','AdsDiagController@destroy');
```

Since `Route::get('adsdiag/{id}/',AdsDiagController@create);` is not generated by `Resourcce` so you need to include in your route explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments to the `action()` helper method in an array, even if it's just one argument:

```
action('AdsDiagController@create', [$record->id])
```